# How to add more RDD to existing RDD in Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a RDD and want to add more RDD to it. How can I do it in Spark?
I have code like below. I want to return RDD from the dStream I have.

```
JavaDStream<Object> newDStream = dStream.map(this);
JavaRDD<Object> rdd = context.sparkContext().emptyRDD();
return newDStream.wrapRDD(context.sparkContext().emptyRDD());
```

I do not find much documentation about [wrapRDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/api/java/JavaDStream.html#wrapRDD(org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD)) method of JavaDStream class provided by Apache Spark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`JavaStreamingContext.queueStream`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html) and fill it with a `Queue<RDD<YourType>>`:

```
public JavaInputDStream<Object> FillDStream() {
    LinkedList<RDD<Object>> rdds = new LinkedList<RDD<Object>>();
    rdds.add(context.sparkContext.emptyRDD());
    rdds.add(context.sparkContext.emptyRDD());

    JavaInputDStream<Object> filledDStream = context.queueStream(rdds);
    return filledStream;
}
```

Comment: Can I convert List of JavaRDD to single JavaRDD?

Comment: union will give me Dstream, but I want JavaRDD as that is the return type of my method.

Answer (score 2):

Since RDD is **immutable**, what you can do is use `sparkContext.parallelize` to create a new RDD and return the new one.

```
List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<Object>;
objectList.add("your content");

JavaRDD<Object> objectRDD = sparkContext.parallelize(objectList);
JavaRDD<Object> newRDD = oldRDD.union(objectRDD);
```

See https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#parallelized-collections